# how to print the user type from his login?

Tags: java, authentication

i cant connect login info with account type, like i want to print "Welcome Manager" when the username and password of the manager is entered..

```
    UserAccount users[] = new UserAccount[3];
    users[0] = UserAccount.createUser("test0", "test0"); <<Username,Pass>>
    users[1] = UserAccount.createUser("test1", "test1");
    users[2] = UserAccount.createUser("test2", "test2");

    personArray = new Person[3]; <<third paramter take UserAccount>>
    personArray[0] = new Manager("Zen","manager@mail.com",users[0],new Date(2/3/2013));
    personArray[1] = new Specialist("Tom","specialist@mail.com",users[1]);
    personArray[2] = new Customer("John","customer@mail.com",users[2],"ny");


    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Main menu");
    System.out.print("(1) User login \n(2) new Customer \n(3) Exit \n==> ");
    int inp = s.nextInt();
    switch (inp) {
    case 1: 
        UserAccount loggedUser = UserAccount.login();

        if (loggedUser != null) {
            System.out.println("----------------------\nHello " + loggedUser.getUsername());
            System.out.println("Welcome to the ITS App\n----------------------");
            <<I want to print here the account type>>
        }
```

Comment: You can strip it from the email with regex

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the Person associated to the UserAccount, you can do something like this

```
if(person instanceof Manager){
      System.out.println("Welcome Manager");
}
```

Alternatively, assuming that Person is an interface, you can put in a function String getType() that is implemented in each class that implements Person to return a String representing the type.  So in your person class, you would have:

```
  public String getType();
```

And then in your manager class, you would put:

```
  public String getType(){
       return "Manager";
  }
```

Then to print out your message you can do this:

```
 System.out.println("Welcome "+person.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after getting a UserAccount:

```
 Person person = Arrays.stream(personArray).filter(person -> person.getUser().equals(loggedUser)).findFirst().orElse(null);

    if(person instanceof Manager){
    System.out.println("Welcome Manager");
    }
```